# Are the xen xe commands available on Oracle VM 3.2?

Tags: command-line-interface, xen, oraclevm

I recently discovered that Citrix has opensourced XenServer, and that XCP (which we have been using) is more or less now legacy and needless.

While looking at rebuilding our systems on XenServer 6.2, I have just realized that oracle VM is actually built atop Xen too, but has so much more going for it in terms of application level integration/configuration and ready templates for practically all of Oracle's enterprise applications.  Now, this is most attractive and I am swayed to go with it.

My only concern at this point is whether Oracle VM allows the xen xe commands for CLI administration.  I will eventually work this out, but I am in a hurry to rig up the systems, and so I am asking in the hope that someone can save me sometime in researching this for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xe` commands are from the XAPI/XE Toolstack, and Oracle VM does not ship with this toolstack. Oracle VM uses the default Xen toolstack, the `xl` and `xm` commands.

Personally I don't thing that's a good thing, Xen can run with some different toolstacks, the Default one, XAPI/XE and LibVirt, so if you already have knowledge of the XAPI/XE Toolstack stay with XenServer.

Here's a picture showing some quick differences:

[image]

The OpenSource XenServer is promising and the development is going very well.

Comment: Awesome feedback, thanks a million.  I am glad I asked.  I am aware of the stack differences and know that XAPI is best, but was unable to quickly find what stack Oracle VM was built on.  I am also familiar with libvirt, and it seems older versions of Oracle VM used to support libvirt, but I cannot tell if it still does so with versions 3.2 and 3.3

Comment: I like the XenProject and the older XCP/Kronos project too, and I am particularly pleased that Citrix opensourced XenServer.  However, IMHO, for heavy users of oracle applications or oracle linux, the VM templates and the ability to weave-in inter-vm application dependencies makes a compelling case for Oracle VM as a useful platform (in addition to XenServer).

Comment: So stick with XenServer. The next version will be awesome: Xen 4.4, 64bit Dom0, tapdisk3 and the anticipated PVH mode.

Comment: Yeah, I do have a compelling reason to stick with XenServer, but will certainly take a deep look at Oracle VM for application driven needs.  One primary reason I was keen to move to Oracle VM was because I hate the idea of needing windows to run XenCenter, but I can work around that by deploying cloudstack on XenServer and using its web-based management interface.  Thanks again for the quick feedback.  You did indeed save me some time.  Marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: Take a look at XenOrchestra. I'm running it for basic thing. If you're a hardcore CLI user, you can ditch XenCenter on Windows with XenOrchestra+CLI. Another thing to consider: XenCenter is now OpenSource, so let's hope for a *nix version of it :)

Comment: Nice one, Vinicius.  XenOrchestra looks good .. and so does [convirtue](http://www.convirture.com/).  Will take a close look at these, and even consider virt-manager(only used this for kvm in the past).  Previously, I tried XVP, XenWebManager, OpenXenManager, and they were either buggy or very limited in practical usage.